# What is a better way rewrite several if loops for conditions in Vue/JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following code in a Vue JS app where I cam trying to change several conditional classes on text, where the text changes colour based on the value of the meter:

```
 <span class="card__form__meter__warning" :class=" { weak : password_weak, 'very-weak' : password_veryweak, strong : password_strong, valid : password_verystrong } ">{{ password_warning }}</span>
```

The following code works but I feel like it is a horrible, repetitive way to do something that is probably a lot easier to achieve:

```
data: {
                name: null,
                emailAddress: null,
                password: null,
                password_warning: 'Strong password required',
                password_veryweak: false,
                password_weak: false,
                password_strong: false,
                password_verystrong: false,
                ...
```

```
                    if (this.meter == 0) {
                        this.password_veryweak = false
                        this.password_warning = 'Strong password required'
                    }

                    if ( this.meter == 25) {
                        this.password_warning = 'Very weak (not strong enough)'
                        this.password_veryweak = true
                        this.password_weak = false
                        this.password_strong = false
                        this.password_verystrong = false
                    } 
                    if (this.meter == 50 ) {
                        this.password_warning = 'Weak (not strong enough)'
                        this.password_weak = true
                        this.password_veryweak = false
                        this.password_strong = false
                        this.password_verystrong = false
                    } 
                     if (this.meter == 75) { 
                        this.password_warning = 'Strong'
                        this.password_strong = true
                        this.password_verystrong = false
                        this.password_weak = false
                        this.password_veryweak = false
                    } 
                    if (this.meter > 75) {
                        this.password_warning = 'Very Strong'
                        this.password_verystrong = true
                        this.password_strong = false
                        this.password_weak = false
                        this.password_veryweak = false
                    }
```

I had real problems removing the previous conditional classes when the meter values changed hence why I ended setting the

```
                        this.password_weak = false
                        this.password_strong = false
                        this.password_verystrong = false
```

for each condition.

I feel like i'm probably making a very basic mistake so any help is gratefully received.

Thanks

-----edit-------

```
computed: {
                password_warning: function () {
                    if (this.meter == 0) {
                        this.password_class = ''
                        return 'Strong password required'
                    } else if (this.meter == 25) {
                        this.password_class = 'very-weak'
                        return 'Very weak (not strong enough)'
                    } else if (this.meter == 50) {
                        this.password_class = 'weak'
                        return  'weak (not strong enough)'
                    } else if (this.meter == 75) {
                        this.password_class = 'strong'
                        return 'Strong'
                    } else {
                        this.password_class = 'strong'
                        return 'Very strong' 
                    }
                },
            }
```

Comment: Why not just have an object (or whatever) with threshold values mapped to the warning and a CSS class?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use conditional classes from an object literal. Use a single data property to store your class name and use that directly:

```
<span class="card__form__meter__warning" :class="password_class">{{ password_warning }}</span>
```

The code for setting `this.password_class` becomes pretty straightforward then.

I would recommend to go ahead and even make both `password_class` and `password_warning` [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) that are derived from the `meter` value, instead of assigning them imperatively.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Do you mind elaborating on what you mean by "derived from the meter value, instead of assigning them imperatively."?  Thanks

Comment: Yes, and no. I'd recommend to use either one computed property for `password_class` and a second computed property for `password_warning` (duplicating the `if`/`else` logic), or to make a single computed property for an object, like `return {warning: 'weak (not strong enough)', class: 'weak'}` and use it like `<span :class="password_strength.class">{{password_strength.warning}}</span>`. Do not use imperative assignment in the computed property calculation.

Comment: Btw I'm not certain how you set your meter, but I'd expect `<=` comparison instead of `==` - what if the meter is set to 60? Alternatively, if this is meant as an enum, maybe use that as the data property from which to derive class, warning, and meter value.